# Como diminuir o tamanho do papel

Tags: css, impressão, impressora

Estou fazendo uma impressão com css print na impressora bematech  MP-4200 TH, o meu conteúdo está em um tamanho bom  personalizado pelo css, porem gostaria de diminuir o tamanho do papel por que esta sobrando um espaço muito grande na altura.

Estava vendo a configuração no Chrome e o tamanho do papel na  impressão esta me width 80mm.

Tem como eu diminuir o tamanho da altura do papel na impressão?

Meu css no print:

```
@media print {
    @page {          
        margin: 0;
    }

        html, body {
            width: 210mm;
            height: 100mm;
            margin:0px;
        }

        .pagina {
            margin: 0;
            border: initial;
            border-radius: initial;
            width: initial;
            min-height: initial;
            box-shadow: initial;
            background: initial;
            page-break-after: always;
        }

        /*body {
            background: #fff;
            width: 302px;
            height: 300px;
        }*/

        h2 {
            page-break-before: always;
        }

        h3, h4 {
            page-break-after: avoid;
        }

        pre, blockquote {
            page-break-inside: avoid;
        }

        .modal-dialog .modal-content {
            border: none;
        }

        .print {
            display: none;
        }

        #minhaTabela_wrapper {
            display: none;
        }

    #myModal {
        width: 110mm;
        height: 100mm;
        border: none;
        margin-left: 1px;
        margin-top: -15px;

    }

        #imprimir {
            margin-top: -30px;

        }   

    .text-print {
        float: left;
        font-size: 10px;
        font-family: Arial;

    }

    .input-print {
        border: none;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 12px;
        width: 110px;
        float:left;
        margin-top: -11px;
    }

        .modal-header {
            border: none;
        }

        #codBarras {
            display: inline;
        }

        h4 {
            font-size: 10px;
        }

        .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_processing, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate {
            display: none !important;
        }

    .larg {
        width:150px;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Cara tira uma foto ai de como está ficando a impress~]ap e desenha com uma caneta os tamanhos e onde vc quer que diminua, vai ficar mais fácil para entender o que vc está querendo... Mas normalmente os formatos de papel tem tamanhos pré definidos tipo A3, A4, A5, F1, F2, Letter, Legal, Tabloid, etc... certamente a sua impressora trabalha com um formato de papel definido, vc tem que descobrir que formato é esse, isso ajudaria tb...

Comment: @hugocsl editei e minha pergunta e coloquei a foto, vou verificar qual é o formato do papel.

Comment: Cara olha o tamanho do seu body e do html tem 21cm x 10cm esse tamanho eh um a5 na horizontal... Tenta mudar isso, ou testa colocando como auto e coloca o tamanho no @Page usando a propriedade size:

Comment: @hugocsl coloquei   no  body `height: auto;` mas ficou a mesma coisa. Colocando a propriedade size no @Page tentei colocando A3 que tem  420 de autura porem mudou só o conteúdo o tamanho da pagina esta o mesmo.

Comment: Cara eu fiz esse teste, mas repare que o tamanho do papel não muda no Ctrl+P, só muda o tamanho que o conteúdo vai ter na hora da impressão. Eu defini para ter 100mm por 120mm, porém a folha da impressora continua como A4, pois essa é um config da impressora, não do Browser... http://prntscr.com/lkskp6 repare que até deu mais de uma folha 1/2, porém a página da impressora é A4 e não consigo mudar pelo css

Comment: Entendi, então é a configuração da impressora? Será que consigo mudar ?

Comment: Vc pode dar uma pesquisada mais a fundo, mas eu não consegui resolver... o máximo que deu para fazer foi definir quanto de conteúdo que vai na folha e não o tamanho da folha... Tipo, vai um conteúdo para caber em uma folha A5, mas se a impressora está configurada pra papel A4 ela vai imprimir no A4 não importa o CSS... Pelo menos foi isso que consegui nos testes aqui infelizmente...  Leia isso pode te ajudar: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/01/designing-for-print-with-css/ e aqui https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/05/print-stylesheets-in-2018/

Comment: @hugocsl, Muito obrigado pela ajuda, o link que em indicou é show, vou verifica a configuração da impressora.Forte abraço.

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema em meu sistema que gera o impresso de uma forma totalmente diferente da sua.
Isso é um problema da impressora conhecido pelo fabricante Bematech.
Neste [link](http://bematechpartners.com.br/wiki/index.php/2017/06/26/problema-impressao-tamanho-do-papel-mp-4000th-mp-4200th-mp-100-mp-5100/) há instruções de como resolver este problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema era na impressora, baixei o software do fabricante e resetei as configurações da impressora e resolveu o problema.
Obrigado.